# How to insert conditional statements in html inside a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my code:

```
var tr = `<tr>
    <td>${flippableTemplate(item['Group 1'])}</td>
    <td>${flippableTemplate(item['Group 2'])}</td>
    <td>${item['Description']}</td>             
    <td>${item['Description2']}</td>
</tr>`;
```

I want to insert conditional statements in it like

```
if (item['A'] != item['B'])
  $('<td></td>').text("Great!").appendTo(tr);
else
  $('<td></td>').text("Oops").appendTo(tr);
```

How do I go about doing that?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Either populate htmls from javascript or use any framework for custom html logic

Comment: @binariedMe Could you please explain what you said? :)

Comment: Yes. In javascript (not html), you can write something like create element like this one and append it  : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp, 
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: @SteveDoson Please share your item JSON.

Comment: @Steve you can refer to these two links

Comment: @binariedMe Still at a loss. If you would kindly make the modifications in the code that I gave and explained it, that would be great. :)

Comment: @Shiladitya `{
   Category: 1,
    Description: 'Description 1.1',
    'Description 2': 'Description 1.2',
    status: 'Status 1',
    'Group 1': 'group1.1',
    'Group 2': 'group1.2',
  },`

Comment: @SteveDoson Where is `A` & `B` key in the `JSON`?

Comment: @Shiladitya That is just a prototype that I was using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/vh1bmfuz/

```js
var item = { Category: 1, Description: 'Description 1.1', 'Description 2': 'Description 1.2', status: 'Status 1', 'Group 1': 'group1.1', 'Group 2': 'group1.2', 'A': 1, 'B': 2}

var matchMethod = function(){
  return ((item['A'] != item['B']) ? 'Great' : 'Ops');
}


var tr = `<tr>
    <td>${item['Group 1']}</td>
    <td>${item['Group 2']}</td>
    <td>${item['Description']}</td>             
    <td>${item['Description 2']}</td>
    <td>${matchMethod()}</td>
</tr>`;

$('table').append(tr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

I've a method that will check & return a string based on condition matched.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks! Also if I had to add an image or a unicode, in this condition, any idea how I can change the size? Because it is getting printed fine, but the size is an issue.

Comment: @SteveDoson Can you please help me to understand the problem more deeper by creating a `jsfiddle`?

Comment: I will show you the line I wrote. It's working fine. Just that the size is a problem.  `<td>${matchMethod(item['Completed'] === true) ? 'unicode' : (item['Completed'] === false && item['Prediction'] === null) ? '--' : 'unicode' }</td>`

Comment: when I am running the snippet, it is saying item has not been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a function that takes your inputs, tests them, and then outputs the template?

```
function appendCell(a, b) {
  const word = a !== b ? 'Great' : 'Oops';
  return `<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>${word}</td></tr>`;
}

const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const output = appendCell(a, b);
```

OUTPUT

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>Great</td></tr>
```

Adjust the code for your requirements.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ac2jd9tt/1/)**